Crashlytics missing required dSYM with same UUID across app versions
I have a dSYM/crash problem in Crashlytics.
Every release i make it complains about a missing required dSYM with the same UUID.
My understanding is that every time i archive my application a new dSYM should be generated with a new UUID.
And that framework crashes should be marked with optional dSYM's.
So how can the dSYM be marked as required, but has the same UUID?
Have i setup a framework wrong so crashltytics thinks its required?
Or is only linked framework's marked as optional?
Have anyone had the same issue ,or any idea on how to find out what framework is causing the crash.
Would be nice to know what framework is causing the crash.
Using both cocopods and drag and drop XCFrameworks.
DWARF with dSYM = true
Strip linked product = No
Strip style = All Symbols
Strip Swift Symbols = Yes

When i unzip my ipa i can find the UUID as a .symbols file.
I can confirm that the other dSYMS is actually there and uploaded and seeing are able to see symbolicated crashes in the dashboard.
I have been in contact with crashlytics support but they were unable to help me.

I have finally figured out what the issue was
In our project we had three debug schemes that cocoapods was not aware of.
So when running pod install the debug flags was not set on the frameworks for these schemes.
Adding this to the podfile, solved the debug flag and got rid of the missing dSYM problem.
project 'Project',
'Develop-Debug' => :debug,
'Stage-Debug' => :debug,
'Release-Debug' => :debug
